# Why is jest.isolateModules not working as expected?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I want to move away from using `jest.resetModules` since I want to reset two modules, but keep one through all the runs.

My original code to get things working as such was bad like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
  require('hooks/useMyProvider');
  const useMyProvider = require('#/');
  api = useMyProvider(); // scoped above
})
```

Then in each test, I would do something like this:

```
// Mock hook since we can't spy on a function
jest.doMock('#/hooks/useActive', () => {
  return () => {
    return [true]
  }
});

// re-require the component that requires useActive so it pulls latest mock
let MyComponent = require('#/components/MyComponent')

const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
```

I tried refactoring to having `useMyProvider` defined once at top of file and removing `jest.resetModules` from the `beforeEach`;

Then I did this:

```
let MyComponent;

jest.isolateModules(() => {
  jest.doMock('#/hooks/useActive', () => {
    return () => {
      return [true]
    }
  });

  MyComponent = require('#/components/MyComponent')
});

const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
```

When I did this in two tests, and swapped out `true` for `false` in the return, whichever test came first would stick. I expected it to change each time since I had isolated the modules.

Comment: Could you show the entire test file which does not work?